# Does Tesseract Provides Confidence score of whole Image?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Tesseract provides confidence score in TSV config, but i am looking for confidence score of whole image processed.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will return confidence score per image.

```
    String datapath = "D:\\Tesseract";
    String language = "eng";
    TessAPI1 api = new TessAPI1();
    TessBaseAPI handle = api.TessBaseAPICreate();

    File image = new File("testocr.png");
    Leptonica leptInstance = Leptonica.INSTANCE;
    Pix pix = leptInstance.pixRead(image.getPath());
    api.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, datapath, language);
    api.TessBaseAPISetImage2(handle, pix);

    int conf = api.TessBaseAPIMeanTextConf(handle);
    System.out.println("conf" + conf);

    // release Pix and Boxa resources
    LeptUtils.dispose(pix);
```

Below maven dependency you need to add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```